# C#: Count occurrences of a string in a list which is in another list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to count occurrences of a string in dynamically added lists in a main list. This is the main list:

```
public static List<string>[] tables = new List<string>[30];
```

This is how I add items to it:

```
public static int takenTablesDayTotal;

public static void AddProductToTable()
{
    int tableNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (tableNum < 1 || tableNum > 30) { throw new Exception(); }

    choiceName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (tables[tableNum] is null)
    {
        tables[tableNum] = new List<string>();
        takenTablesDayTotal++;
    }

    tables[tableNum].Add(choiceName);
}
```

And this is how I have tried to do the counting, but it doesn't seem to work right for some reason (starts at 1 and stops counting there when the required string is detected)

```
salesProductDayTotal = tables.Where(s => s != null && s.Contains("string")).Count();
```

I'm not sure how to make this work, so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to deliminate the two-nest structure.
Then use `Count` to get what you want.

**For example** - count the daily apple sales number

```
List<string>[] tables = new List<string>[30];
tables[0] = new List<string>{
    "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"
};
tables[1] = new List<string>{
    "Peach", "Apple", "Watermelon"
};
tables[2] = new List<string>{
    "Mango", "Grape", "Apple"
};

//the daily sales count of Apple.
var dailyAppleSalesCount = tables.Where(x => x != null)
        .SelectMany(s => s).Count(x => x == "Apple");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the `List<List<string>>` into one large `List<string>`, and then count the products.

You don't need to use `Contains`, IMO (`"Chicken soup"` is probably a different product on the menu that `"Spicy Chicken Soup"`), so it simplifies the condition a bit.

```
salesProductDayTotal = tables
    .Where(t => t != null)
    .SelectMany(products => products)
    .Count(p => p == "string")
```

You could also use a `GroupBy` clause to do this calculations on all the products at once.

---

Explanation of your problem:

You were using the `Count` on the outer list, the list of tables. So you had just "one match" for each table that *contains* the product at least once.